# selectText action always wait till the end of timeout

Tags: testing, automated-tests, timeout, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to clear the input field with selectText and then press the delete key.
When the test is run, selectText action always waits until timeout ends before selecting the input text. Is that a bug or normal behavior?
The element was correctly found as typetext was run almost as soon as the page load. Selector timeout if left to default(10000ms)

Browser: Firefox 61(64bit)
OS: Windows 10
TestCafe: 0.21.0

```
test('Select Text wait till timeout', async t => {
  const firstNameInput = Selector('#first-name');

  await t
    .typeText(firstNameInput, 'Max')
    .selectText(firstNameInput)
    .pressKey('delete');
)};
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this behavior is incorrect. The TestCafe team is going to fix it in the context of the following issue:

https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2080

---

Just a follow-up, we have fixed the issue described in this thread:

https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2080

The fix is available in TestCafe of version 0.22.0 and higher.